# MySQL- if conditon fails (#1064 error)

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(user1.name, ' ', user2.name)
    IF(user1.salary < user2.salary) as userSalary
FROM `users` AS user1
LEFT JOIN users AS user2 ON user1.id = user2.id
ORDER BY user1.salary ASC
```

I am trying to find all users which have a lower salary than the next user (in the same table). The table has a simple structure:

```
Fields:

ID (PK) | name | age | address | salary
```

This is the error I am getting at the moment:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(user1.sallary < user2.sallary) as userSallary
FROM `users` AS user1
LEFT JO' at line 3
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are missing a comma but I doubt this query is of any use. What does "next" user mean? Rows in a SQL table do not have any inherent order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at IF statement at [MySql Docs](http://MySql%20Docs)

> IF search_condition THEN statement_list
>       [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
>       [ELSE statement_list] END IF

Or at IF() [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html):

IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)

```
If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL), 
IF() returns expr2. Otherwise, it returns expr3.
```

Your sentence should be something similar to:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(user1.name, ' ', user2.name)
    IF(user1.salary < user2.salary, user1.salary, user2.salary) as userSalary
FROM `users` AS user1
LEFT JOIN users AS user2 ON user1.id = user2.id
ORDER BY user1.salary ASC
```